# DataGrid common style isn't being applied for whole DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want all my DataGrids to have one common style but I'm not succeeding at it. I have separate .xaml file for that (DataGrid.xaml) but only DataGridColumnHeaderStyleBase applies properly but DataGridStyleBase doesn't.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/AnalyticalReporting.UI;component/Themes/DataGrid.xaml"/>
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </UserControl.Resources>
```

**Usage:**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Grid"
              ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyleBase}"
              Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyleBase}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="" Binding="{Binding Path=Title}" Width="238" FontSize="10" CanUserSort="False" IsReadOnly="True" >
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                </Style>
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
///etc.

</DataGrid>
```

**DataGrid.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnHeaderStyleBase" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EFF5FD" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.5"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="10" Text="{Binding}" Padding="6"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridStyleBase" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="Red"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="RosyBrown"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="GridLinesVisibility" Value="All"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalGridLinesBrush" Value="#B3B8BE"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalGridLinesBrush" Value="DarkGray"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

My question is: how can I apply both of these styles (for whole DataGrid and for DataGridColumns)?

**UPDATE:**

If I apply Style explicitly

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Grid"
              ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyleBase}"
              VerticalGridLinesBrush="#B3B8BE"
              GridLinesVisibility="All"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              IsHitTestVisible="False"
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="DarkGray"
              RowBackground="#FFFFFF" AlternatingRowBackground="#EFF5FD">
```

I'll have this (what I want):
[image]

But If I apply DataGridStyleBase instead

```
<DataGrid x:Name="Grid"
              ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyleBase}"
              Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyleBase}">
```

I'll get this:

[image]

As we can see DataGridColumnHeaderStyleBase was applied but DataGridStyleBase wasn't applied. No errors at all.

Comment: Why wouldn't `DataGridStyleBase` be applied? You will get an error if the `Style` cannot be resolved. So what happens in your case?

Comment: @mm8, pls, see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGrid}}"` to `<Style x:Key="DataGridStyleBase" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">`

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help :c